# Effect of increasing page load sample size on end user experience

Tags: google-analytics

I have a website which has around 500-600 vists per week. I would like to increase the sampling size to 100% in the google analytics tracking code.
I would like to know if this has eny effect on the performance of my website

Comment: By default, the Analytics tracking code sampling is always at 100%. Do you mean SiteSpeedSampleRate to track page load timing?

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the comment above Google has an option to set sample sizes:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setSampleRate

This will not affect you visitors (since the pixel is sent anyway,  sampling happens during data processing).

I don't think it will make any difference if you have only a few hundred visitors, though (I'm guessing that Google is smart enough not to use sampling unless necessary, and in any case you should use setSampleRate to make your samples smaller, not bigger).

Answer (score 0):

**2016 answer**

According to the [official doc](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1205784?hl=en), the default sampling rate is 1%. If your site has little traffic, you can increase this rate with `setSiteSpeedSampleRate()`